# Variables within a function

Tags: python, python-dateutil

Writing a function to calculate date based on relativedelta.
How do I make the 'frequency' a variable?
e,g, relativedelta(years=5), ability to define frequency: "years", "months", "days" etc..

Tried f-string literal but i think the apostrophe is giving issues.

```
def date_ago(date, period, frequency):
    """date: "yyyy-mm-dd"
    frequency: "years", "months", "weeks", "days"
    period: interger
    """
    date_ago = datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d") - relativedelta(f'{frequency}={period}')
    return date_ago.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')


date_ago("2021-03-31", 5, "years")
```

ANS: '2016-03-31'

Comment: you can make it conditional for instance if the input value of frequency is 'yearly' then the condition for that case:

    for instance : if frequency == 'week':

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking to *expand* the keyword arguments, not make one string argument!

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists

```py
    relativedelta(**{frequency: period})
```